# Unable to run strata() in R

Tags: r

I am learning about strata sampling in R and was trying to run the strata function. I run into the same error each time i try to run this function - when i run strata() from class notes provided by the professor, when run an example from ?strata - below is the example from help(strata) and the error message i receive when i try to run it. I am puzzled. I get the same error message no matter which strata() i run - any ideas how to overcome this? Any recommendations are appreciated.

```
# Uses the 'swissmunicipalities' data as population for drawing a sample of units

data(swissmunicipalities)

# the variable 'REG' has 7 categories in the population
# it is used as stratification variable
# Computes the population stratum sizes
table(swissmunicipalities$REG)
1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
589 913 321 171 471 186 245 

# do not run
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
# 589 913 321 171 471 186 245 
# sort the data to obtain the same order of the regions in the sample

data=swissmunicipalities
data=data[order(data$REG),]

# the sample stratum sizes are given by size=c(30,20,45,15,20,11,44)
# 30 units are drawn in the first stratum, 20 in the second one, etc.
# the method is simple random sampling without replacement 
# (equal probability, without replacement)  

st=strata(data,stratanames=c("REG"),size=c(30,20,45,15,20,11,44), method="srswor")
```

> Error in strata(data, stratanames = c("REG"), size = c(30, 20, 45, 15,
>   :    all arguments must be the same length

```
# extracts the observed data 
getdata(data, st)
```

> Error in is.vector(m) : object 'st' not found

```
# see the result using a contingency table 
table(st$REG)
```

> Error in table(st$REG) : object 'st' not found

Comment: It is working for me. I don't see any error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied and pasted this in, and got the same error, but I typed it in by hand and it worked just fine. Also, since `stratanames` is a single value, you should use `stratanames = "REG"`. Finally, make sure you do not have the `survival` packaged loaded, and if you do, you may need to use

```
st <- sampling:::strata(swissmunicipalities, stratanames = "REG", 
                        size = c(30, 20, 45, 15, 20, 11, 44), method="srswor")
table(st)

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
30 20 45 15 20 11 44
```